# Query with less cost running longer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a strange situation. I have two queries where the only difference is -

> one query has CREATION_DATE > SYSDATE -4 and another one has
>   CREATION_DATE < SYSDATE -4

The "CREATION_DATE > SYSDATE -4" query is taking way long to execute and provide output than the "CREATION_DATE < SYSDATE -4" query. One obvious explanation could be that the cost of the longer running query would be more than the other.

Strange thing is that when I ran explain plan for both,

> - both the queries have the same cost
> - longer running query has less cardinality and byte than the shorter running one.

I am attaching the screenshot of explain plan for both. 
Probably I am missing something, but how could a query that have same cost as another and on top of that, having more cardinality and byte run shorter ? Could anyone please explain this ?

[image: Shorter running query]

[image: Longer running query]

Comment: are you sure that the estimated cardinality is the actual cardinality? You statistics could be out of date. What is the result of select count(*) for eache query?

Comment: also try to look at **actual execution plan** by autotrace in sqlplus

Comment: Try to use gather_plan_statistics plan a see what how is the query really processed. Also sometimes Oracle does not fully take into account some index features. For example The multi-column index has "too many" column and INDEX RANGE SCAN has to traverse too many pages. Executed both queries with "set autotrace traceonly explain stat", and then compare the amount of "physical reads" and "consistent gets". "consistent gets" shows how many pages in total were processed by query execution. (PS: which application are you using?)

Comment: I would like to mention one thing - I am using plsql developer (allaround automation) to run the query. I am reporting the above depending on the time it takes for the tool to fetch and show me an initial dataset. Is it a true indicative of the time the queries are taking for execution ? I hope I am not doing anything wrong here.

Comment: count(*) for "CREATION_DATE < SYSDATE -4" is 1559919 and count(*) for "CREATION_DATE > SYSDATE -4" is 0

Comment: @SubhasisM: you have wrong statistics. Pls update statistics for your table. Pls check the actual exec plan as agent5566 says.